# Paper backup of Core descriptor wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, backup

As I understand it, using `dumpwallet` for a non-descriptor wallet in Core will give you the wallet seed in WIF format. This seed can then be used with `sethdseed` in a new wallet, thereby recovering the original wallet. So in effect, one can make a paper backup of a Core wallet.

But with descriptor wallets, `dumpwallet` does not work.

Is there a way to make a paper backup of a Bitcoin Core descriptor wallet?

Comment: For normal (not "paper") backup and restore see https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/112176/13866

Answer (score 4):

This is working now, with version 23 of the bitcoin-core:

###### How to create the descriptors wallet?

1. `createwallet("my_wallet", False, False, "", False, True, False)`
2. `getnewaddress("my_label", "bech32")`

###### How to save the wallet?

1. `backup = listdescriptors(True)['descriptors']`
2. Dump `backup` into a json file

This file can be printed or saved for later reuse.

###### How to restore the wallet?

1. `createwallet("my_wallet_2", False, True, "", False, True, False)`
2. Load the json file into `backup`
3. `importdescriptors(backup)`
4. `getnewaddress("my_label", "bech32")`

This should give the same BTC address as before.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to make such a backup of a Bitcoin Core descriptor wallet. There are open PRs that will allow you to export the descriptors stored in the wallet, however these have not been merged yet.

Comment: thanks. Am I right in thinking that backing up just the descriptors is not sufficient to recover a wallet? Or will the PRs you mentioned allow Core users to make paper backups?

Comment: Descriptors that contain private keys will be sufficient to recover the entire wallet.

Comment: Where are these PRs? I searched but apparently I'm bad at finding them.

Comment: The PR is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/21500) but now it is merged.

Answer (score -2):

when you create the wallet, you will be shown the seed used. that is when you write the seed down.

Comment: I downvoted. This answer is not correct for Bitcoin Core's wallet, but may be true for others.

Comment: yeah im used to electrum and similar so I just assumed that btc core would work the same, my bad