# Descriptor Wallets are way more confusing than legacy

Tags: json-rpc, backup, output-script-descriptors

how do you dump backup into a json file?
then how do you load the json file into backup?

> " How to create the descriptors wallet? createwallet("my_wallet",
> False, False, "", False, True, False) getnewaddress("my_label",
> "bech32") How to save the wallet? backup =
> listdescriptors(True)['descriptors'] Dump backup into a json file This
> file can be printed or saved for later reuse.
>
> How to restore the wallet? createwallet("my_wallet_2", False, True,
> "", False, True, False) Load the json file into backup
> importdescriptors(backup) getnewaddress("my_label", "bech32") This
> should give the same BTC address as before. "

Comment: The quotation is from https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/102601/13866